# How to check if a double can fit into a float without conversion to infinity

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point

Is there a standard way to check if a 64 bit floating point number can be converted to a 32 bit one without being converted to +/- Infinity?

I know it can be checked afterwards for +/- Inf.

`Convert.ToSingle()` won't do this.

Comment: doesn't comparing to `Single.MinValue` and `Single.MaxValue` help?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.minvalue.aspx

Comment: @Knaģis A few doubles above `Single.MaxValue` convert to `Single.MaxValue`. There is a discussion of this aspect of floating-point in the “Polyspace” section of this post: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/25/Static-analysis-tools-comparisons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to test whether a `double` value `d` will convert to `float` without yielding infinity, you can test whether `d`'s absolute value is strictly below the `double` written as `3.4028235677973366e+38` (that is, `0x1.ffffffp+127` in hexadecimal). This number is the exact limit between doubles that can be converted to float and those that cannot.

To expand a little, the last finite float is:

```
0x1.fffffep+127   (3.4028234663852886e+38 in decimal)
```

What would be the next `float` number if type `float` had more exponent bits is:

```
0x2.000000p+127   (3.4028236692093846e+38 in decimal)
```

The numbers that are closer to the former than to the latter are rounded down to the former. The limit is the midpoint of the two numbers:

```
0x1.ffffffp+127   (3.4028235677973366e+38 in decimal)
```

Comment: That number is similar to single.MinValue (as suggested by @Knagis), but not equal. I don't get why.

Comment: @IanC You are right, my value is slightly above. `Single.MaxValue` is the last finite floating-point single-precision number, but in the “round-to-nearest” mode, a few values above this number are considered to round down to it because it is “nearest”. The exact limit is midway between Single.MaxValue and what would be the next `float` value if there were more exponent bits.

Comment: Wow, interesting. So the following should work: if (Math.Abs(value) < 3.4028235677973366e+38d) result = (float)value; // correct?

Comment: @IanC Yes, it should. Note that I answered this question without having ever written a line of C#, so I would appreciate if you test it and report :) If C# accepts hexadecimal floats, use the notation `0x1.ffffffp+127`, it makes the intention much clearer.

Comment: It works using 3.4028236692093846e+38 as a test. But testing value > Single.MaxValue also works.

Comment: Wouldn't the exact value to test for overflow be Single.MaxValue plus a large enough epsilon to get the next *double* (not float)?

Comment: i.e. 3.4028234663852888E+38

Comment: @IanC When converting from double to float, the conversion is done to the nearest float. This is how the doubles written as `0.99999999999` and `1.000000000001` both round to `1.0f`. In the case of the last finite float, it is the same. All the values in the half ULP below it and and all the values in the half ULP above it round to it. So what matters is the float type's ULP around this number. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place )

Comment: Yes, but the test is done in double precision, so one needs an increment in double precision. I just tested and proved the number I proposed is correct. It detects a number above Single.MaxValue that testing (value > Single.MaxValue) cannot. The number you gave does not detect the overflow. But the idea you gave helped me, thank you!

Comment: Correction: Testing against the built-in constants always works in C#.

Comment: @IanC I am not sure I am following. Could you express this last remark in the form of a C# program I could play with at http://ideone.com/ ?

Comment: // the smallest epsilon possible at (double)float.MaxValue;
double epsilon = 3.7778931862957162E+22;
double test = float.MaxValue + epsilon;

if (test >= 3.4028234663852888E+38d)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Overflow caught");
}

if (test >= 3.4028235677973366e+38)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Overflow caught");
}

Comment: Going full circle, I now know why testing (Math.Abs(value) > (double)float.MaxValue) is 100% valid. It's a double precision check, so single precision rounding isn't a factor.

Comment: To prove, add the following: if (test > (double)float.MaxValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Overflow caught");
}

Comment: I think you missed the output. It says "Others constant, overflow caught". "Pascal" isn't there. Your constant didn't work.

Comment: @IanC “Pascal” isn't there **and f is a finite float** (printed as `3.40282346638529E+38`). I thought your goal was to detect whether converting to float was going to produce an overflow? So “my” test correctly predicted that there would not be an overflow when converting `test` to `float`.

Comment: My goal is to check if a double is outside the range of a float, which causes it to convert to inf (or round down as you said). Your answer helped me to guarantee that I am detecting what I need. But I don't get your interpretation of the program. Let's put it another way. My constant is more sensitive at detecting numbers that exceed the bounds of single (and could therefore be converted to inf).

Comment: The way you have written your question is “Help me tell whether the conversion of a `double` to `float` will yield infinity”. This is different from “Help me tell whether a `double` is in the range of `float`s. The two questions are different. I answered the first one.

Comment: Ok, understood. So your constant will detect values that will become Inf, but mine won't?

Comment: My answer is the exact test for whether `(float)test == +inf`, according to the precisely defined rounding rules in the floating-point standard. Comparing to `Single.MaxValue` is safe in that it never answers “true” for a number that would produce infinity, but it rejects a few values that would be converted to a finite float according to the rules. It's a very small difference, you don't have to worry about it, I am only insisting because I would not want you to be left with the impression that floating-point is somehow unreliable.

Comment: The semantics you describe is exactly what I want, so I am satisfied. Thank you @Pascal.