# Test to see if double be safely cast to float

Tags: java, double, precision

I'm trying to squeeze some performance out of serializing `Double`s.

I figured that if a double can be stored in a `byte`, `int`, or `float` (such that there is no precision loss), I can store less bytes.

Currently I can test for `int` and `byte` like this:

```
    if (doubleValue == null) {
        storeEmpty();
    } else {
        if ((doubleValue % 1) == 0) //we have no fraction
        {
            if (doubleValue > Byte.MIN_VALUE && doubleValue < Byte.MAX_VALUE) {
                storeByte(doubleValue.byteValue());
            } else if (doubleValue > Integer.MIN_VALUE && doubleValue < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                storeInt(doubleValue.intValue());

            } else {
                storeDouble(doubleValue);
            }
        } else {
            storeDouble(doubleValue);
        }
    }
```

Is there a trick for testing if the `double` falls into `float` precision range?

Comment: How does a double stored in a byte not lose precision?

Comment: When the value stored is within the range of the byte.

Comment: I suppose so... Seems like you're really hurting for bits to do all this work.

Comment: Why wouldn't `float` be handled the same way `byte` and `int` are?

Comment: `(float)myDouble == myDouble`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099818/how-quickly-check-whether-double-fits-in-float-java

Comment: @bradimus because float has a sign, exponent and mantissa

Comment: @EmersonDallagnol good find. thanks!