# Infer smallest possible data type without accuracy loss

Tags: java, floating-point, inferred-type

I have an input, which is a `String`. The input will always be a `String` representation of a decimal number, like one of these examples:

```
  3.14159265
  314159265
  314159265e5
```

I have defined an `enum` called `Types` that has two members: `Types.FLOAT` and `Types.DOUBLE`.

I want to write a function that will return `Types.FLOAT` for all inputs that can be represented as a `float` **without loosing accuracy**, and `Types.DOUBLE` for all others that can be represented as a `double` **without loosing accuracy**. If the number is too accurate for `double`, something like `null` should be returned.

**As we all know**, `float` has a size of 32 bits while `double` has a size of 64 bits.
Casting a `double` to a `float` will result in a loss of accuracy, so for example:

```
 3.14159265 --> 3.141592
 314159265 --> 314159200
 314159265e5 --> 314159200e5
```

Some things to clear up:

- I don't actually want to parse my input into one of these types. **I just need the information so I can pass it on to Hive**.
- Not using the **smallest accurate** data type is not acceptable.

Comment: Sorry for being overly clear, my last question was butchered by people that don't know the difference between `float` and `double`.

Comment: Can you check `Float.parseFloat(str);` and then if not able to parse, check `Double.parseDouble(str);`?

Comment: @notyou `parseFloat` will parse anyways, but while loosing a lot of accuracy.

Comment: I think the best approach would be to parse it using `Float` and `Double` and again using some arbitary precision library and comparing the result. Handling float parsing yourself can become ugly.

Comment: Well then try something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099818/how-quickly-check-whether-double-fits-in-float-java. FYI it’s **losing**, not loosing.

Comment: @Neo I agree. That could be possible.

Comment: What does “represented as a `float` without [losing] accuracy” mean? Some possible meanings are: (a) When this decimal numeral is converted to a `float`, the defined value of the `float` is exactly equal to the value of the decimal numeral. (b) When this decimal numeral is converted to a `float` and then converted back by Java‘s default string formatting / converted to the numeral with the fewest decimal digits that uniquely distinguishes the `float` value, the result is equal to the decimal numeral. (c) When this decimal numeral is converted to a `float` and then converted back…

Comment: … to a decimal numeral with the same number of decimal digits as the original numeral, the result is equal to the original numeral. (d) All decimal numerals as many significant digits as this decimal numeral and the same position of the initial significant digit can be converted to `float` and back to decimal numerals with the same number of significant decimal digits without change.

Comment: Sorry to present you with these technical and somewhat subtly different options, but understanding what you really want is needed to provide a correct answer to the question. If you do not understand these differences, then please explain more about what you are trying to accomplish, especially what “losing accuracy” means.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 major parts of a floating point number, the Significand and the Exponent. According to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 32 bit can represent 7.22 digits and an exponent of -126:127. A double can do 15.95 digits and -1022:1023 digits in the exponent.

So I would do something like the following (sudo code)

```
public static FloatingPointEnum getType(String number){

    // Looks for the digits ignoring possible leading / trailing zeros
    int numDigits = getDigits(number);

    // Counts the leading / trailing zeros
    int exponent = getExponent(number);

    if(numDigits < 7 && exponent > -126 && exponent < 127){
        return _32Bit; 
    } else if(numDigits < 15 && exponent > -1022 && exponent < 1023){
        return _64Bit;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a nice solution, but are you sure the exponent and the digits are decoupled in size?

Comment: Note: -126, 127, -1022 and 1023 are all binary exponents, while 7 and 15 are decimal digits. Decimal exponents can be derived.

Comment: I would try `numDigits <= 7`. But for truly **minimal** representation, a binary number of digits would be needed.

Comment: if you have the number .000<125 more zeroes...>6789 you'll need a double for that. It's 4 digits of precision with an exponent of -128, which will need to fit into a double.

Comment: Ah yes, I probably need to use <= / >= for all operations also.

Comment: 1.40129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125 × 10^-45 is exactly representable as a `float`, but this code would return `_64Bit`, even if its errors in the exponent range were fixed. And there are numbers with fewer than seven  significant decimal digits that are not exactly representable as a `float` but for which this code would return `_32Bit`.